# Excel Autofill not working

Tags: excel, ms-office, autofill

I'm using Excel 2016. I want to autofill numbers (I.e 1,2 when dragged would autofill with 3 and so on).

For some reason, when highlight the cells of both 1 and 2 when I trying to drag to autofill to the cell below all three cells now contain the value 1.

Autofill is turned on in the options>advanced menu.

Thanks for all help in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my own question. I had filtered columns that were sorted and with some values filtered out. Although the cells I was trying to figure were adjacent this stopped the autofill from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After you drag you have to select "fill series" from the fill options menu that pops up.

Comment: That doesn't pop up for me, but I did figure it out. Thank you!